# Using Drive search results causes an iterator error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I keep getting this error with my Apps Script code:

> Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.

This error occurs on the lines:

```
var priceChangeImage = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Price Change_" + tickerSymbol + ".png").next();

var earningsRevisionsImage = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Earnings Revisions_" + tickerSymbol + ".png").next();

var FgpeImage = DriveApp.getFilesByName("F-GPE_" + tickerSymbol + ".png").next();
```

The execution context:

```
  //Slide4
  var shapeSlide4 = slides[3].getShapes();
  var priceChangeImage = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Price Change_" + tickerSymbol + ".png").next();
  var newImage4 = shapeSlide4[0].replaceWithImage(priceChangeImage);
  newImage4.setWidth(650);
  newImage4.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

  //Slide5
  var shapeSlide5 = slides[4].getShapes();
  var earningsRevisionsImage = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Earnings Revisions_" + tickerSymbol + ".png").next();
  var newImage5 = shapeSlide5[0].replaceWithImage(earningsRevisionsImage);
  newImage5.setWidth(650);
  newImage5.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

  //Slide6
  var shapeSlide6 = slides[5].getShapes();
  var FgpeImage = DriveApp.getFilesByName("F-GPE_" + tickerSymbol + ".png").next();
  var newImage6 = shapeSlide6[0].replaceWithImage(FgpeImage);
  newImage6.setWidth(650);
  newImage6.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);


  newSlideNotify(slideUrl);

}
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is failing because you are blindly calling [`next()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#next()) on a [`FileIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)), without first checking that there was a result for your search.

The proper method for working with File and Folder Iterators is to call [`hasNext()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#hasNext()) first.

This example gets the first result from a search for a given filename, and throws an error if your search returned no results (so you know if you need to fix your search or your file names).

```
function getFirstFileWithName_(searchName) {
  var allFiles = getAllFilesWithName_(searchName);
  // Were there any results from the search?
  if (allFiles.length === 0)
    throw new Error("No files with name '" + searchName + "'");

  return allFiles[0];
}
function getAllFilesWithName_(name) {
  var results = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
  var files = [];
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    files.push(results.next());
  }
  return files;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below given code:

```
    var shapeSlide4 = slides[3].getShapes();
        var filesPriceChange = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Price Change_"+tickerSymbol+".png");
        if(filesPriceChange.hasNext())
        {
              var priceChangeImage = filesPriceChange .next();
        }
          var newImage4 = shapeSlide4[0].replaceWithImage(priceChangeImage);
          newImage4.setWidth(650);
          newImage4.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

          //Slide5
          var shapeSlide5 = slides[4].getShapes();
    var filesEarningsRevisions = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Earnings Revisions_"+tickerSymbol+".png");
        if(filesEarningsRevisions .hasNext())
        {
              var earningsRevisionsImage = filesEarningsRevisions .next();
        }
      var newImage5 = shapeSlide5[0].replaceWithImage(earningsRevisionsImage);
      newImage5.setWidth(650);
      newImage5.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

      //Slide6
      var shapeSlide6 = slides[5].getShapes();
var filesFgpe = DriveApp.getFilesByName("F-GPE_"+tickerSymbol+".png");
if(filesFgpe.hasNext())
{
      var FgpeImage = filesFgpe.next();
}
      var newImage6 = shapeSlide6[0].replaceWithImage(FgpeImage);
      newImage6.setWidth(650);
      newImage6.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);


      newSlideNotify(slideUrl);
```

Comment: "try this" with no explanation is a poor answer.

Comment: This code gives me an error saying the URL should be http or https?
But they are images in my drive?